# ofstream causes corrupt pointer when closing application?

Tags: c++

As topic says, that's the conclusion i can come up with.

The code itself isn't mine, so i am modifying it, but i can confirm that when i us ofstream, in any way at all. I get an error on shutdown (Only in Release Mode). Searched on it, and it seems to be pointer issue.

Something like this will case the issue for example:

```
out.open("test", std::ios::trunc);
out.close();
```

It can be run once, doesn't matter.

I don't get what i am supposed to do, i though close was supposed to clean the pointer.

but it doesn't matter, even this doesn't work:

```
std::ofstream* o = new std::ofstream("test.wav", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
o->close();
delete o;
```

The ofstream themselves work properly, i can use them as expected and all is fine.
And there shouldn't be anything else interfering with this.

Any ideas at all?
I am hoping it's some easy issue i am just missing out here.

**Update**

The error i am receiving is as follows:

```
onexitbegin_new = (_PVFV *) DecodePointer(__onexitbegin);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why use pointers at all? And if you desperately want to use pointers, why not use smart pointers?

Comment: Do you get the error when your program contains *only* those two lines? This sounds like you have a bug elsewhere in your program that causes corrupted memory.

Comment: Updated with the error.

I don't really care if i use pointers or not. i just tried using an ofstream pointer to see if it solved the problem, but it didn't.
I can't really run the program with only those 2 lines sadly, but i find it weird that it's Only when i use ofstream that this happens.
any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the update, that not an error, that's a line of code (probably from a library). What *happens* when you run your program? Does it crash? Have you tried running in a debugger? What is the call-stack (in other words, where in *your* code is the crash)? Or do you get build errors? What are those?

Comment: Yeah, memory is being corrupted. It quite likely has nothing to do with `ofstream`. Look elsewhere. Consider stack corruption, heap corruption, errant pointer usage, C-style stuff like `memcpy`, etc. Reduce the program down to the absolute minimum that demonstrates the problem and work from there.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , oh, well problem is, it runs fine with Debug, no error anywhere.

Comment: @CareyGregory , Ah damn, had no idea other issues could come up from using this. this makes things extremely complicated as i can't track it:S

Comment: All the more reason to suspect memory corruption. Running it in debug mode moves stuff around and hides the error.

Comment: If your program runs fine in a debugger, but crashes otherwise, it's typically a sign of you using an uninitialized pointer. When running in a debugger, the debugger will zero out all local variables, meaning pointers will be `NULL`, but if you don't run in a debugger the local variables will not be initialized automatically. That can lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you have a check for `NULL` pointers and the pointer is not initialized.

Comment: JoachimPileborg, the thing is, there is a check for all pointers. And this Only appears when using ofstream, which is why i thought some kind of pointer with ofstream was the issue. As everything is fine as long as i don't use ofstream.

Comment: More specifically, uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and will be seemingly random. Very seldom will they be zero (which is the same as `NULL`), so your check for `NULL` will think that the pointer is okay, even when it's not.

Comment: What you need to do is to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that have the problem, and show that for us. Otherwise it will be impossible to actually help you, and point out what's wrong.

Comment: Just for fun, if you have a pointer which you do not initialize at the declaration, initialize it to `NULL` in the declaration and see what happens?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You want me to just int* t = NULL, somewhere?
But i am not even using pointers, i am using ofstream normally, which shouldn't be a pointer right?

Comment: The I say again, please make a small but *complete* example program which have this problem, if at all possible. Also, are you using VC++ and Visual Studio? When *run* the debug version (normal run, not debug) and if it crashes then you get the option to debug it. There you should be able to get a stack-trace (the function call stack), go up to "your" code and look around there for variables with weird values, and possibly edit your question to include some relevant lines. If everything looks normal it indeed looks like a memory corruption issue. (To be continued...)

Comment: If it's a memory corruption issue you have to look for writing out of bounds of arrays, look at all pointer (if you have any) access, everything that has to do with pointers and arrays. Also, the line where the crash happens indicates that it could be in the [`atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) code, is the code using [`atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) anywhere?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , Can't reproduce it in a manner that matters sadly. I got no pointers, and i have tried commenting out all arrays so nothing is of use that i put in (my code), so basically, the only thing i do, is crease an ofstream. Nothing more. And no, there is no atexit code anywhere.

Comment: "it runs fine with Debug" is a red herring. Your program is ill-formed. it is invoking *undefined behavior* **somewhere**. "I can't really run the program with only those 2 lines sadly." You miss the enormity of that suggestion. Eliminating all but two lines (the stream open and close with **no** pointer junk) will work, and is not ill-formed. Start adding back code from there, running in a **debugger** at each step.

Comment: @WhozCraig , so you are saying i should have ofstream, and then try eliminating pointers until it works?. Is there no way for me to know which pointer breaks it?

Comment: Valgrind would probably help out immensely. And no, you said the exact *opposite* of what I did. Start with just the stream basic, then begin adding things *back*. One way or the other though, this should be run in a debugger. And if your platform supports Valgrind, for heaven's sake use it.

Comment: @WhozCraig , thing is, it happens neither way, just activating an ofstream will cause it. But can't really do much, the program is extremely large. "Solved" it by using an "ofstream" alternative that was actually built in to this software. Not a solution itself, but as it's not my entire software, i can't really track it down.
Learned much though, thanks!